# How do I download my Gradle project external dependencies to a specific folder?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to download my dependencies to a specific folder in my build as part of my build process e.g. build/lib . I can't find documentation which shows how to do this, I'm sure there is a straightforward way to do it that I'm missing. My current(shortened) build.gradle is the following. The project compiles and executes test correctly.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()        
}         

dependencies {
   compile(
           'aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0',
           'log4j:log4j:1.2.17',
           'batik:batik-svg-dom:1.6-1')
   }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my little researh about advanced dependency management with Gradle http://stackoverflow.com/q/31662781/746347

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont know if you tried this, but see if this works

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/output/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}
build.dependsOn copyToLib
```

It worked for me.

Credit where its due :-) : http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_can_i_gather_all_my_projects_dependencies_into_a_folder

Comment: I had just come across that in the [cookbook](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook#Cookbook-GatheringalldependencieslibrariesJARsinonefolder) and tested it. Works exactly as I wanted.

Comment: I am getting an error as "Could not find property 'copyToLib' on project". gradle version is 2.1