# How to download Android Gradle project external dependencies to a folder?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-library

It's a similar problem to:
[How do I download my Gradle project external dependencies to a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385451/how-do-i-download-my-gradle-project-external-dependencies-to-a-specific-folder)

with the addition of gradle "android" plugin.

I tried this:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_can_i_gather_all_my_projects_dependencies_into_a_folder
but there is no `configurations.runtime` when building with android plugin.

Answer (score 0):

if you run the command `gradle dependencies` you'll see all the `configurations.*` objects.

In particular you'll see that for each sourcesets we have:

- `provided`
- `compile`
- `apk`

For sourcesets other than the `main` one, the name of the sourceset is used as a prefix. This means you'll get things like

- `debugCompile`
- `releaseCompile`
- `flavorCompile` (if you use flavors)
- etc... with `provided`, and `apk` as well.

All you have to do is query these different configuration objects to get their files.